# Chrome Prevent text selection not working on select all

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I have a very simple HTML page with divs, and I want to disable the user selection only for one of these divs. It's working well on Firefox, but fails on Chrome. 
What fails is: when I select all the page with the mouse, copy it and paste it in a notepad, I get all the text, even the one supposed not to be selectable. The same thing happens when I ctrl+A the whole page.

Here is the HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Test</title>
<style> 
    .unselectable {
        -webkit-touch-callout: none;
        -webkit-user-select: none;
        -khtml-user-select: none;
        -moz-user-select: none;
        -ms-user-select: none;
        user-select: none;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div>Start</div>
<div class="unselectable">Unselectable text</div>
<div>End</div>

</body>
</html>
```

When I remove the first div, or the last div, it works well: I do not get the "Unselectable text" in my copy/paste.
*My Chrome version is up to date: 47.0.2526.111* 
I would like a solution without any Javascript, or only vanilla: I do not have jQuery on my page, and do not want to.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Have you tried this ? https://ctrlq.org/code/19637-prevent-people-copying-text-web-pages

Comment: @Vinod Balakrishnan Thanks, but I do not have jQuey on my page (and do not want to :)). I edited my post to mention this.

Comment: That code can easily be ported not to use jQuery. That being said I wouldn't count on this as some sort of security/DRM feature. If people really wanted to copy some text they could use the dev tools or copy it from the source code directly.

Comment: @JonSnow Sure, this is not a security issue on my side, and sure it could be translated to vanilla javascript. But don't you guys think this is a Chrome bug, as it works in Firefox, and works in Chrome if no element is present before or after?

Comment: @toni07 I think this could be a bug since user-select is still in its experimental stage according to MDN...This buggy issue in webkit browsers was as also highlighted on this site....https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/u/user-select/..hmmm.......very interesting

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too, I found the solution using: `unselectable="on"`

```
<div unselectable="on" class="unselectable">Unselectable text</div>
```